# LogFile not creating in Local using Python logging module running with Docker

Tags: python, docker, docker-volume, python-logging

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
logger = logging.getLogger('Mainer')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
format = "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
filename = "Reckon_APP.log"
handle = TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename, when="midnight", 
interval=5)
handler.setLevel(logging.WARN)
formatter = logging.Formatter(format)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S" 
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

I got to know  logfile will not create directly  when the app is running in docker. So I used docker volumes to create it. I run the following command. Given local path to desktop(in which path, the file should be created and absolute path is the log file name that I given in the app.
`docker run -v /C/Users/DELL/Desktop:/Reckon_APP -p 80:80 --name my_APP My-Own-app`
And the app is running with out errors, Still the file is not creating in my local.

Comment: In Docker it's somewhat more typical to set your logger to write to stdout (use a `logging.StreamHandler` instead of the `TimedRotatingFileHandler`).  You can then view the logs with `docker logs`.  In a production setup, the common log-collection tools know how to get the logs out of Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not set up to run this in docker, but at a guess, it looks like you are missing the directory in this line:

```
    logname = "Reckon_APP.log"
```

Instead:

```
    logname = "/Reckon_APP/log.log"
```

Comment: ThankYou very much Sir. Its working fine. As I first ran the application in local it directly creates the logfile. While running in docker it did not worked. Now ,it's working with your changes.